# Cannot install pyqt4 on Mac OSX 10.11.6

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyqt

I'm trying to install a python2.7 program that has PyQt as a dependency. My mac has 3.5.2 default, and so I made a virtual environment using virtualenv with python 2.7.

There's a bunch of other dependencies, but they are all working except for PyQt. I've got the source code downloaded and unzipped, but typing in

```
(venv)$ python configure-ng.py --qmake ~/anaconda/bin/qmake-qt4 --verbose
```

returns

```
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
/Users/evansmith/anaconda/bin/qmake-qt4 -spec macx-g++ -o qtdetail.mk qtdetail.pro
make -f qtdetail.mk
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../anaconda/lib/qt4/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I../../../anaconda/include/qt4/QtCore -I../../../anaconda/include/qt4 -I. -o qtdetail.o qtdetail.cpp
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -o qtdetail.app/Contents/MacOS/qtdetail qtdetail.o    -L/Users/evansmith/anaconda/lib -lQtCore -L/Users/evansmith/anaconda/lib 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__Unwind_Resume", referenced from:
      _main in qtdetail.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [qtdetail.app/Contents/MacOS/qtdetail] Error 1
Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
```

Before you say "brew pyqt" I've heard that homebrew doesn't work well with virtualenv. Should I use it anyways?

The only other thing I can think of is that the virtualenv python can't reach the qmake file in /anaconda/bin/. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using Anaconda already.

Just create a new environment with `conda`

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
```

activate it:

```
source activate py27
```

and install PyQt 4:

```
conda install pyqt
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was preoccupied with the holidays.

Comment: I was able to install, but the program still doesn't work. I think it's their fault.

Comment: You can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your (original) problem. i.e. the installation.